# pi-character of a compact Hausdorff space does not exceed its tightness

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I'm studying parts of "recent progress in topology", the chapter about homogeneous spaces. In one of the corollaries (corollary 5.5) authors use this theorem, and reference to a paper from Šapirovski for the proof, but I can't find the link or anything for it. Does anybody know the proof, or a paper or book or anything I can find it there?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: In the original and II I did not find such a chapter, is it in III?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hi! Yes it's in there, but there is an online pdf of this chapter. This is the link: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.vanmill/papers/papers2014/ArhangMillRecentProgressIII.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjPx8HsoMnuAhUyzYUKHY43DfYQFjADegQIBRAC&usg=AOvVaw3OPagozaS2pbLOBEuJeTi9

Comment: You don't have access to B. E Šapirovski , $\pi$-character and $\pi$-weight in bicompacta, Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 223 (1975), no. 4, 799–802. ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm afraide not.

Comment: Note that that chapter also names Juhász' two books as a reference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in cardinal functions, you should surely look at Juhász' classic book(let)s Cardinal functions in topology and Cardinal functions in topology - ten years later. These made the subject quite popular for a while. They're rather self-contained introductions that contain detailed proofs, also of the underlying set theory combinatorics in some cases.

In the latter I found as theorem 3.14 (a), that for compact Hausdorff spaces we indeed have $\pi\chi(X) \le t(X)$. The proof is too long to reproduce here, but it's based on the characterisation of tightness in compact Hausdorff spaces using so-called free sequences, which is also proved in this second book. He also refers to some original Šapirovski papers (some in Russian, some in English translation ), so going to the original papers should be doable too, if your library has access to these. But the exposition in Juhász is fine, and more self-contained I think.

I believe the original paper is

B. E Šapirovski , $\pi$-character and $\pi$-weight in bicompacta, Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 223 (1975), no. 4, 799–802.

Comment: Thank you so much, I saw the proof in the book!

Comment: @MahanMehravard You're welcome. These are almost always the first books I look for on my shelf whenever a question on cardinal functions arises. Classics IMO. Put it next to the Handbook of Set-theoretic Topology and Engelking...

Comment: It’s also in Section $7$ of Dick Hodel’s *Cardinal Functions I* in the *Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I love Engelking's book! And thanks again!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you! I think this one is less dated with better typography!

Comment: @MahanMehravard it has somewhat fewer proofs than Juhász has.  But a handy overview.